# Gradient Stripe Background Color Understanding

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

I need to understand this alignment! I have done a lot of search for this problem, but still unclear.

Please take a look at this pattern :

[image: gradient stripe pattern]

For generating this with CSS we should write something like this:

```
 background:repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,lime ,green 25px ,lime 25px,green 50px );
```

which will create a 50x50 square like pattern above, but I cannot understand the logic behind this! Somewhere I read that two colors in same stop point will make the color sharper, but the interpolation and merging are not mentioned! I will be so glad if someone can help me to understand template used in CSS function.

Comment: Or you just use a *repeated pattern* as a background-image, or you  have look on https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/.

Comment: Here are a [couple](https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/) [links](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-understanding-css3-gradients--net-10451) to help out.

Comment: they just want to write a post or better an incorrect post , for example in  @RedBreast  link at 7th line he mentioned I think that.... it is show that he is not sure about that.

Comment: @S.A.Parkhid: Initially I thought you were asking about two things (1) how the gradients work and produce a repeating pattern and (2) why your background is not similar to the image. But after reading your comment I am a bit confused. Could you clarify if my answer helps (or) if you are looking for something totally different?

Comment: thanks for your answer , I think it is correct , look at comments please

Comment: @S.A.Parkhid Your message doesn't makes any sense. Do you mean that the source is not reliable? I would trust *Chris Coyier*'s posts blindfolded.

Comment: @RedBreast  ,I don't want to make someone reliable or unreliable ! but please read the 7 line from top , I think he is miss something in comparision with Harry's answer !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
background:repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,lime ,green 25px ,lime 25px,green 50px );
```

This background setting can be interpreted as follows:

- The gradient image is placed at an angle of 45 degree to the container.
- The gradient starts with the color lime and will gradually change to green color at the 25px mark.
- At 25px the color shifts abruptly from green to lime and continues to shift to green till 50px.
- The gradient is a repeating linear gradient and so will repeat until the entire container is filled up with the pattern. Repetition is handled like tiles and you can think of it as placing equal sized tiles around each other so as to fill up the entire area.

Without using `repeating-linear-gradient` you would get only a 50px x 50px background image.

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.repeating-gradient {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, lime, green 25px, lime 25px, green 50px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="repeating-gradient"></div>
```

---

If you want to achieve an effect like in the image then you need to change your gradient to the below:

```
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, lime, lime 25px, green 25px, green 50px);
```

This background setting can be interpreted as follows:

- The gradient image is placed at an angle of 45 degree to the container.
- The gradient starts with the color lime and will continue to hold the color till the 25px mark.
- At 25px the color shifts abruptly from lime to green and continues to be green till 50px.
- This pattern will again repeat till the entire size of the element is covered and would therefore produce a striped pattern.

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.repeating-gradient {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, lime, lime 25px, green 25px, green 50px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="repeating-gradient"></div>
```

Comment: my css code is doing write job and I want to be clarified with linear background logic and I think you have describe it true.

Comment: @S.A.Parkhid As long as it is doing what you need then no need to change it. I just provided an alternate option that matches the output of the image in question :) If it helped understand, please consider marking it as accepted (or) if you are waiting for something better then no issues.